# Thread error in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

**I have gotten this error:**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control
>   'Redlight' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created
>   on.

Redlight and Greenlight are pictureBoxes.
Basically, all I want it to be able to do is alternate between each picture every second.
I searched on this website for similar errors, I see it has to do with "Invoking", but I don't even know what that is, can someone enlighten me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace EMCTool
{
    public partial class EMCTool_MainForm : Form
    {
        bool offOn = false;

        public EMCTool_MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void EMCTool_MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(timerCallback), null, 0, 1000);
        }

        private void timerCallback(object obj)
        {
            if (offOn == false)
            {
                Redlight.Show();
                offOn = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Greenlight.Show();
                offOn = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You  get the Cross-thread error when you try to update a UI element from any thread it was not created on.

Controls in Windows Forms are bound to a specific thread and are not thread safe. Therefore, if you are calling a control's method from a different thread, you must use one of the control's invoke methods to marshal the call to the proper thread. This property can be used to determine if you must call an invoke method, which can be useful if you do not know what thread owns a control.

Refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) for more

Try this .This works fine for me

```
   if (pictureBoxname.InvokeRequired)
                    pictureBoxname.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
          //access picturebox here
                    }));
                else
        {

  //access picturebox here
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, how does this Invoke thing work and what does it do for me?
EDIT: I've tested and it worked.

Comment: the Invoke method delegates the UI-related processing to be done on the thread it was created on i.e. the UI thread.

Comment: @user1880591 It sends your call to the thread where the control was created, and that one do the job.

Comment: Is invoking using a lot of resources and performance?  I feel like I have to use invoke for everything I put on the form.

Comment: @user1880591 Using a Windows Forms Timer instead of a System.Threading.Timer will avoid all of the cross thread operations in the first place...

Answer (score 2):

In WinForms projects better use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` as it calls the `Tick` event on the UI-thread automatically:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer;

private void EMCTool_MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer { Interval = 1000 };
    _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    _timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (offOn) {
        Greenlight.Show();
    } else {
        Redlight.Show();
    }
    offOn = !offOn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution would be to use System.Timers.Timer which has SynchronizingObject property so set this, and it will work:

```
timer.SynchronizingObject = This
```

Or to use System.Windows.Forms.Timer as it won't raise exception (it raises Tick event on UI thread).