# Is using a ton of InvokeRequired methods cost effective?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a question topic here: [Thread error in C# Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513364/thread-error-in-c-sharp-windows-form/17513529)

It seems that for everything that is involved with the threading timer must use InvokeRequired methods.  So, I got a bunch of things that need this.  Is using this a lot going to use up a lot of computer resources?

Comment: Yes.  It is a very strong hint that you should be using System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead.  Most certainly in that linked question, there's completely no point in using an asynchronous timer for it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is using this a lot going to use up a lot of computer resources?

It doesn't necessarily use up "computer resources", but using `Control.Invoke` and `Control.BeginInvoke` does have overhead.

One good option, in many situations, is to try to batch your calls which require `Control.Invoke`/`BeginInvoke`, which attempts to minimize the number of marshaling operations.